Unbiasedness Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney Test
There are many different alternatives discussed for the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test. One alternative is $P(X < Y) + \frac{1}{2}P(X = Y) \neq 0.5$. There are compelling arguments for this, such as the fact that the test statistic is essentially the sample equivalent of this probability, and that it represents the broadest alternative for which the test is consistent.
However, the test is not unbiased under this alternative. The example below demonstrates this. It might be unbiased under additional assumptions (I suspect equality of variances of the ranked data). Unfortunately, I have not found any research on this; research typically focuses on other alternatives, such as stochastic ordering (where one cumulative distribution function is always greater than the other), under which the test is unbiased. My question, therefore, is: Are there assumptions (other/weaker than stochastic ordering) under which the test is unbiased for this alternative?
set.seed(123)
reps <- 10^3
p_wmw <-  rep(NA, reps) 
for(i in 1:reps){
  g1 <- rnorm(80, mean = 0, sd = 5)
  g2 <- rnorm(20, mean = .2, sd = 1)
  p_wmw[i] <- wilcox.test(g1, g2)$p.value
}
print(mean(p_wmw < .05))

prints: 0.013

I'd say that "everyone" in your opening sentence is too strong. I regard calling that the null about as sensible as calling "independence" the null in a two-sample t-test.

I understand. Removed that part.

Could you clarify why the output of your simulation demonstrates that WMW is biased? Npt implying that your are incorrect in doing so, just that I can not quite follow the reasoning. Thanks

I quote from this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248957/how-can-a-mann-whitney-u-test-return-a-p-1-00-for-unequal-means on CV "The Mann-Whitney U test, has as its most important feature is that it is an unbiased test of difference of location as it ignores non-normality. Finally, the difference of location measure of the Mann-Whitney U test is...wait for it...the U-statistic.".

@jginestet: If the power of a test can be smaller than the significance level, a test is called biased, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555289/how-to-make-biased-test-unbiased-i-need-someone-to-confirm-if-i-understand. My simulation shows the this is the case for the WMW test (under the alternative mentioned).
Difference in location alternative is a stricter alternative than stochastic ordering. It implies a shift in the entire distribution of one random variable relative to another. Thus, difference in location imples stochastic ordering.

And why does "mean(p+wmw<.05)=.013" show that the power is less that .05?

What actual significance level is your test being conducted at?

@jginestet - because the entries in p_wmw are the p-values from 1000 tests, and only 1.3% of them were smaller than 0.05; if the test was unbiased, at least 5% of them would be less than 0.05, with some adjustment for the sample size of 1000 thrown in.

+1.  I believe equality of variances does not suffice, or even equality of any finite number of moments, to conclude the test is unbiased.

@JulianKarch, thanks for the definition of an unbiased hypothesis test. I decided to run my own simulation (with 2000 replicates). With your exact parent distributions, I get a proportion P of significant results equal to .95%. Even less than your 1.3%. But given that both our numbers of replicates are small, probably not a signhificant (no pun intended) difference. Then I ran the same test again, but this time with H0 true (both parent distributions have a mean of 0). I got P=.7%.  ...cont

...cont. So is unbiasedness defined as power greater than the desired alpha (e.g. 5%), as power greater than the actual, true alpha (under the conditions of the test)? In the same simulation, with the same samples, I also tested the Student's t-test. In your scenario, I got P=0.05%, while with both means equal to 0 (H0 is true),  I got P=0%. So is the Student t-test also biased? Note that when I swapped the sample sizes, MWU in your scenario gave P=16.35%, and with Null true, P=16%. So both much greater than 5%. Seems your scenario is a case where there is 0 power (and misbehaving alpha error)
