# Statistical power and sample size determination using Kruskal-Wallis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, sample-size, statistical-power, kruskal-wallis-test

I have data that represents treatments applied to a given number of subjects in two or more groups. After each treatment, the subjects in each group are appraised to be of quality 1-5 and the number in each group having each ranking are counted. 
Some mock data for this process:

| Treatment | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 | 20 | 0 | 10 |
| b | 0 | 5 | 13 | 3 | 0 |
| c | 1 | 4 | 12 | 4 | 0 |

I use the Kruskal-Wallis test to determine if the medians of any of these groups are significantly different from the others. <

However, if I were able to use something like a Chi-square or t-test, I could then calculate an effect size for each treatment and then determine what sample size would be necessary reliably pick up such an effect size.

Is there a method that would allow me to do this (effect size calculation and statistical power/sample size determination) for the KW test?

Comment: KW test is not a test of the medians. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33759/do-we-need-to-report-the-median-or-the-mean-when-using-a-kruskal-wallis-test